# Magento 1.8 : Cannot disable cache through cache storage management

Tags: magento-1.8, cache

I want to disable all cache storage in Magento.

But, When trying using the Admin Panel Cache Management nothing is disabled.

Is there another way to disable the cache besides the Admin panel?

Comment: you can clear the var/cache folder but I'm not sure if this cleans the cache the way that cache management does in magento

Comment: how i will clear the var/cache folder. Mention steps ??

Comment: connect to your server using ftp program like FileZilla and navigate to the folder, then just delete the files inside

Comment: i tried FileZilla but FileZilla keep telling that Connection refused by server

Answer (score 1):

Got to cmd. Use:

- windows: `php bin/magento cache:disable`
- ubuntu: `sudo php bin/magento cache:disable`

Answer (score 0):

System > Cache Management

On the left side, click Select All, and from the dropdown Actions menu select Disable > Submit .

To ensure that the cache has been completely cleared, click Flush Magento Cache and Flush Cache Storage in the upper right side of Cache Storage Management menu.

Comment: System > Cache Management On the left side, click Select All, and from the dropdown Actions menu select Disable > Submit........ .But when i click Submit buttion then it will not disable anything. This is my problem.

Comment: Can you diff your code between a clean version of 1.8? Something is over-riding it then that you aren't telling us about.

Comment: please give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

To manually disable cached items if the Admin backend is not available:

The cache settings are stored in the `core_cache_option` table

value 1 = enabled, 0 = disabled

Use phpmyadmin or the following mysql command to disable:

```
update core_cache_option SET value = '0' WHERE value LIKE '1';
```

Then clear cache to reload config settings or manually delete cache by deleting all `var/cache/mage--?` subdirectories.

If this is not disabling all cache items, then you have a Magento cache directory permissions problem and [Magento is storing its cache in an alternate location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779624/722112).

Answer (score 0):

Check app/etc/env.php it should be writable for web server user.
This file stores configuration of cache